# Why doesn't init script create every table in the script?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, datatables, mariadb

I am trying to make an init script for MariaDB, using docker-compose.

Only the 3 first tables are created, so player_team_relation and player table are not created.

```
create table if not exists user
(
    user_id       varchar(255) primary key,
    username      varchar(30)  not null,
    password_hash varchar(255) not null
);

create table if not exists history
(
    history_id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    user_id    varchar(255) not null,
    game_date  timestamp    not null,
    constraint user_history_constraint foreign key (user_id) references user (user_id)
);

create table if not exists team
(
    team_id     bigint auto_increment primary key,
    history_id  bigint      not null,
    player_name varchar(30) not null,
    score       bigint      not null,
    hasWon      bool        not null,
    constraint history_team_constraint foreign key (history_id) references history (history_id)
);

create table if not exists player_team_relation
(
    player_id bigint not null primary key,
    team_id   bigint not null primary key,
    constraint player_ptr_constraint foreign key (player_id) references player (player_id),
    constraint team_ptr_constraint foreign key (team_id) references team (team_id)
);


create table if not exists player
(
    player_id   bigint auto_increment primary key,
    user_id     varchar(255) not null,
    player_name varchar(30) not null,
    wins        int         not null,
    losses      int         not null,
    score       bigint      not null,
    constraint user_player_constraint foreign key (user_id) references user (user_id)
);
```

I have tried creating the database many times by deleting the volume and creating a new container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example why error checking is always recommended:

The statement

```
create table if not exists player_team_relation
(
    player_id bigint not null primary key,
    team_id   bigint not null primary key,
    ...
```

will fail, since it's not possible to define multiple primary keys per table. For more information on primary keys please check the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#primary-key-column-option).

About your column definitions: Are you sure you want to use `BIGINT` (signed integer) instead of `BIGINT UNSIGNED` for auto_increment? Do you really need BIGINT? The maximum value of `INTEGER UNSIGNED` is 4294967295 - more than half of the world's population.

Comment: I see, I have use to primary key(player_id, team_id). Also you are correct I should use unsigned

Comment: I also found out I had the tables created in wrong order, player_team_relation has to be last, cause team and player table has to be created before there can be created a relation